# Connecting raspberry pi 3 to my Laptop

Tags: raspberry-pi3, remote-desktop

Im trying to use my laptop as a monitor, keyboard and mouse for my Rasbperry pi 3. I have connected via Remote Desktop Connection several times. But now it is showing error. I've used Advanced IP Scanner for finding Rpi's IP address. But the address shown against raspberrypi.mshome.net is not working and this name has two to three ip addresses. Following is the output of the command ipconfig:

```
Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::ac0c:bc0f:9eb1:d1b%4
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.127
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1

Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::a5d0:981a:2f49:ca41%3
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.202.65
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

I've read somewhere that making the subnet mask and IP same for both my laptop and Rpi will work but I don't know how to do it. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You should use VNC if you want to manage it from your computer. You have to connect to Raspberry Pi with integrated RealVNC, but before you connect it you have to open the settings.

If you connect the cable with RaspBerry, you should assign a static ip:
Example:
**cmdline.txt**
ip=<client-ip>:<server-ip>:<gw-ip>:<netmask>:<hostname>:<device>:<autoconf>

```
... rootwait ip=192.168.1.200::192.168.1.1:255.255.255.0:rpi:eth0:off ...
```

next step; You will connect Putty via ssh and enable VNC.

you type ssh **raspi-config**
 raspberry pi open settings window, then enter **interfacing settings** and **enable VNC**

then install realvnc or something software your pc and write your pi ip for connecting.

this page tells you how: Connect Raspbbery pi VNC [VNC Connect](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md)

Comment: I am unable to use my Rpi because I dont have any monitor or keyboard attached to it. I was using it with my laptop.

Comment: Insert the memory card into your computer and update the cmdline.txt file. You do not need a keyboard and monitor.

Comment: This is the text in cmdline.txt file...    dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=tty1 root=PARTUUID=8d32dbd5-02 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait quiet splash plymouth.ignore-serial-consoles ip=192.168.137.79

Comment: I have Raspbian Jessie in Rpi

Answer (score 1):

**Example cmdline.txt:**

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait

ip=<client-ip>:<server-ip>:<gw-ip>:<netmask>:<hostname>:<device>:<autoconf>
```

with these variables, the value of the ethernet port must be the same

```
ip=192.168.5.200::192.168.5.1:255.255.255.0:rpi:eth0:off
```

for example :

```
Ethernet Adapter:
    Ip Address:         192.168.5.1
    Network Address:    255.255.255.0
```

cmdline.txt updated version:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline rootwait ip=192.168.5.200::192.168.5.1:255.255.255.0:rpi:eth0:off
```

then create a file and ssh the name and then insert this file into your boot/ folder
then insert the memory card into the raspberry and start it up. After 4 to 5 seconds after raspberry is turned on, connect to raspberry with putty.
The address you will connect to is cmdline.txt The ip address you wrote to 192.168.5.200

[connection diagram](https://ibb.co/eZLEpS)